# How Will I set different environments for production and development in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, windows, express, environment-variables

How Will I set different environments for production and development in nodejs in current project scope only without using any module?
I am working locally and want to setup different environment on localhost only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `process.env` -

```
process.env['VARIABLE'] = value;
```

Also recommend to look at [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). Here's an article explaining it's usage - [Managing environment variables in Node.js](https://medium.com/@rafaelvidaurre/managing-environment-variables-in-node-js-2cb45a55195f).